# Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial Theta and Incident Rate Ratios (IRR)?

Tags: r, zero-inflation, incidence-rate-ratio

I am trying to determine the best regression model for data with many zeros; I have about 200 with non-zero DS scores and 600 with zero DS scores.

```
#* Testing the dispersion compared to the mean through variance and mean; variance is much bigger (ZINB model)
> var(fenis$DS)
[1] 3.797932
> mean(fenis$DS)
[1] 1.104545

#check the variance ratio:
> var(fenis$DS)/mean(fenis$DS)
[1] 3.438457
```

I interpret this mean the variance is much bigger (3x) than the mean and as such a zero-inflated negative binomial model is appropriate.

```
> summary (pen.mod)
zeroinfl(formula = DS ~ age + straight + white + everR + Per + Thw + pen_recode + pen_satisfaction, data = fenis, 
    dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.94226 -0.45690 -0.32328  0.07285  8.56963 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         0.7642407  0.2713512   2.816  0.00486 ** 
age                -0.0002917  0.0054957  -0.053  0.95767    
straight           -0.0311581  0.0710383  -0.439  0.66094    
white              -0.0097287  0.0796854  -0.122  0.90283    
everR               0.0412445  0.0837160   0.493  0.62224    
Per                 0.1200082  0.0253462   4.735 2.19e-06 ***
Thw                 0.1013996  0.0324083   3.129  0.00176 ** 
pen_recode         -0.0855688  0.0435471  -1.965  0.04942 *  
pen_satisfaction    0.0398461  0.0230395   1.729  0.08373 .  
Log(theta)         16.4575309 21.4695528   0.767  0.44335    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         2.543739   0.729746   3.486 0.000491 ***
age                -0.003502   0.014518  -0.241 0.809360    
straight            0.670302   0.181671   3.690 0.000225 ***
white               0.041116   0.212991   0.193 0.846927    
everR              -0.027583   0.224843  -0.123 0.902361    
Per                -0.866754   0.097538  -8.886  < 2e-16 ***
Thw                -0.204216   0.077270  -2.643 0.008220 ** 
pen_recode         -0.003261   0.112865  -0.029 0.976953    
pen_satisfaction    0.078840   0.063512   1.241 0.214483    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 14041543.7856 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 77 
Log-likelihood: -936.7 on 19 Df
```

However, several videos I see say (offhand) that a positive and significant theta (mines is 16.46 but not significant) means that ZINB model is appropriate. This leads to two questions:

1. Does an insignificant theta mean the model is not appropriate?
2. Assuming the model is appropriate, I'm trying to create the Incident Rate Ratios (IRR) for the significant coefficients, I've seen several functions (negbinirr in mfx is one) but when I try to calculate the IRR myself the values are different. I have been calculating IRR through exponentiating the coefficients:

```
expCoef <- exp(coef(pen.mod))
expCoef <- matrix(expCoef, ncol=2)
colnames(expCoef) <- c("Count Model", "Zero-Inflation")
expCoef
```